# XAMPP : My input (name and pass) always has root and password inside of it..how so?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

Today I was trying to create a login page with PDO class in PHP. It worked fine but my problem is my input always have a "root" string value for my first input, and a password inside my second input. Why and how can I erase that? I tried to put a "placeholder" inside of each input, and it still doesn't replace it. Oh, by the way, my input has a "yellow" background...kinda weird. And when I erase it manually, they return white as usual..

This is my code :

```
<?php

include_once('user.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $object = new User();
    $object->Login($name,$pass);
}

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did u per chance store the password for the username with your browser when prompted?

Comment: Yellow background => probably you told your browser to remember a username & password.

Comment: Problem is I didn't specified my browser to remember any values. I tried to delete all kind of cookies, data, etc.. And it is still there.

Comment: The above code seems to be correct tho. U tried a different browser already?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I did not. On firefox though, my input is empty, as wanted :) But still, my question is still there : How can you erase browser's remembered values ON Chrome??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache, or saved credentials problem.

Try:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
```